# Updating database without using button? PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

May I know If it is possible? 
Updating MySQL Database without using button, I mean something like script.

**Scenario:**
I want to have running script that will search for a value that will meet the condition I want then it will automatically update the value.

**Example:**

I have the columns named  - `dateStarted`, `dateExpiration` and `status` so if `dateExpiration` is today it will change the value of `status` from `ACTIVE` to `INACTIVE`. 
**PS:** `dateStarted` + 30 days = `dateExpiration`

This is my ideal codes so far but don't know how I will call the data and update it without using button something like it must be running in background.

```
$dateExpired = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateStart. ' + 30 days'));
$dateExpired2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateStart. ' + 90days'));

$status = "FRESH";

if(strtotime($dateStart)<strtotime('-30 days')){
$status = "INACTIVE";
}

if(strtotime($dateStart)<strtotime('-90 days')){
$status = "DORMANT";
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: a trigger https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Hi, @Fred-ii- Thanks, but its better than CRON job?

Comment: I had thought of cron also actually, but wasn't 100% sure if that was the idea here. Seemed like a trigger was more fitting, least for MySQL that is.

Comment: Is MySQL Trigger can be done in PHP sir?

Comment: no, you need to create it yourself inside your SQL control panel

Comment: see this page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: I will try this thanks, but can you post this as answer so I can vote up this?

Comment: You're welcome, it has been done. *Cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to automatically update a database based on an event, you can use a MySQL trigger.

Example from the manual:

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON account
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->     IF NEW.amount < 0 THEN
    ->         SET NEW.amount = 0;
    ->     ELSEIF NEW.amount > 100 THEN
    ->         SET NEW.amount = 100;
    ->     END IF;
    -> END;//
mysql> delimiter ;
```

Reference:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

The trigger first needs to be create inside an SQL control panel.

If you wish to run a cron job, which may be an option for you, consult the following:

- [How to create cron job using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)
- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428

Comment: Problem Solved, I will accept this as answer although I  used CRON jobs. Thanks again sir!

Comment: @Edmhar I'm glad to hear it. I thought I'd add a few links in regards to cron jobs in my answer, just in case. *Cheers*

Comment: Yes, I used the links you provided as my references. Thanks again sir!